# Type : Extract only properties from class including any

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extract properties from class to create a type.

`ts-essential` comes in very handy with `OmitProperties` !

Only my problem is `OmitProperties<T, Function>` will not only remove the class methods but also every property that is of type `any`.

```
type GetProperties<T> = OmitProperties<T, Function>

class Foo {
    foo: string = '';
    bar: any | null = null;
}

export type FooProperties = GetProperties<Foo>; //  only { foo: string; } =(
```

Any idea how to improve this to include every properties, including the ones typed as any ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=49&pln=15&pc=1#code/PTAEBcGcFoFNMrAduAlgQwDagFA-AJ4AOsoACqgMYDWA0rAZAEIEBqWArrADwAqANKFYA%20UAF5QAb1ABtWqFRJQ1BgHsAZqF4BdAFxa520LAAe4ZABNIQ0AH5Q8-UlgA3WACdQAXxkqCGrW0AbhxTIlV3cAhiUgB5AFtUcDJ3VRJI1Hg%20QTJRCQSk7PIqOgZmNk4eAXJhYRCcEFxCElAAcVhk1PS0LN480ALOtI8eyCKAMQ4kSjRVJGE8Skx0BFBx1VUpHFAd0HUN-Uhwd0UAc3FQAHJLkN3QACN0d310JAJQAB9QJA5MbAkfn8Ql48GEIlFmqR1qoUsMMvALu0ht1MmNoXVQI1QHNMO9pPtVIdjmcgt5xAAKPBAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unknown` instead of `any` (actually, this is applicable to almost any case of using `any`):

```
class Foo {
    foo: string = '';
    bar: unknown | null = null;
}

export type FooProperties = GetProperties<Foo>; //  only { foo: string; } =(

// type FooProperties = {
//    foo: string;
//    bar: unknown | null;
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `PickKeysByValue` type to ignore `any` types.

```
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N; 

type PickKeysByValue<T, V> = { 
  [K in keyof T]: IfAny<T[K], never, T[K] extends V ? K : never> 
}[keyof T];
```

```
export type FooProperties = GetProperties<Foo>;
// type FooProperties = {
//     foo: string;
//     bar: any | null;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=5&pln=21&pc=1#code/PTAEBcGcFoFNMrAduAlgQwDagFA-AJ4AOsoAkgGYCCSBAPACoA0oAmiwHIB8oAvKAAZQsAB7hkAE0igAFAEZQAMlAMAlKAD8bUAC5QHANy58xUgAVUAYwDWAaVgFIAIQIA1LAFdYjFq578Ab1xQUABtW1BUJFBrBwB7ChUAXT1KGnoGcKSWJFgAN1gAJxZM2yThMUlpV01QCL1cgsKeHABfUNiCBOSDPFEiOMLwCFNQAHkAW1RwM0K4kiHUeB9QM39xqfAVixt7Rxd3TC9tri5enBBcQhJQAHFYGbmFtGWGdcnp2fmil8gVgDEPEhLGg4kguHhLJh0AhQP84nFQAEcCEQhQEXpIOBClEAOZ8UAAckJvVRoAARuhCnp0LRQAAfUBIDyYbD8Zms0molGoihIGSqAKtNp9EQDIYjG7wuJfZ5LaT8e6Pb6LZbSs4XMDXUjS2U-eUE5GXMnouKY7F43rG1GU6mgWkEBlMlmYK1gYU4IA)

---

Also keep in mind that anything that is typed like `any | null` will just collapse to `any`.